# Windows Server 2008 R2 - Failed login auditing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, login, audit, eventviewer

I am having issue with configuring Auditing on the server in order to catch failed and successful network logins.

This morning we found one of our test machines with a strange login on the locked screen. Definitely not a user that exists on our domain. The user that saw this had to restart the machine in order to log in. I only found out afterwards so was unable to see the locked screen myself. I've been asked to investigate, but all I found on the affected client and Domain Controller were very vague log entries:

1. Client event viewer:

   - TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager log:

     - Listener RDP-Tcp received a connection
   - Security log:

     - No entries

Since then I've made few changes. On the Domain Controller Policy I have enabled Audit account logon events and Audit logon events. [source](https://serverfault.com/questions/391734/how-to-enable-audit-failure-logs-in-active-directory)

Also followed a further guide from the same thread I've enabled Active Directory Change Events

This is where I am now when checking Event Viewer on the DC in Security logs:

- Audit Failure, which contains account name and time. Event ID: 4771, Failure code 0x18, Pre-authentication Type: 2.

Based on this [source](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4771) I can see it's because of bad password. But it doesn't say from where was the log-in, or to which remote machine.

If I provide the correct password, it creates Event ID 4768, saying a Kerberos authentication ticket was requested, no result code. Nothing in following entries about successful login.

How can I get that into my logs so I am able to track down the issue should it happen again in the future?

To summarise, I need to see all attempted, successful and failed logon attempts on the network. Hopefully I will be able to narrow these logs down to a target IP address to show only logs referring to a machine suspected of being breached. Is that possible without any additional tools/software?