# Windows AD. Is there a limit of successful authentications requests per given account?

Tags: windows, active-directory, authentication, rate-limiting

We're running bulk automation scripts in our environment. Hundreds of threads simultaneously that use the same  AD account for authentication. At some point we got this account locked out while no unsuccessful logins detected. All logins are successful, but the account gets locked out anyway. That makes us think there is a limit of successful login requests, but I couldn't find any information for such unusual matter. Normally you'd never reach it.

Comment: `That makes us think there is a limit of successful login requests` no there is not.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no limit of successful authentications.

The limit on *unsuccessful* logins before lockout is usually configured in the default domain policy, under Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Account Policies -> Account Lockout Policy.

[image]

You probably want to check and make sure that you're actually logging unsuccessful attempts.

[image]
(Image snagged from [this related answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/391734/how-to-enable-audit-failure-logs-in-active-directory).)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We created a user and assigned  fine-grained password policy to it with no lockout parameter. Will see how it goes.